# There is already an object named 'Applications' in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I got this error in my asp.net webapi service when I call method `Membership.ValidateUser(email, password);`.
I am using EF 4.3.1. DB created using this code

```
 using (var db = DbFactory.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating new database...");
                db.Database.Create();
                Console.WriteLine("Initializing with initial objects...");
                db.Database.Initialize(true);
            }
```

I get this error only once on first start of my service.
Does anybody know why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have an object named 'Applications' in the database the first time your application starts.
Does the code snippet you provided only run at startup?
Try dropping the object through the database management engine, and then re-running your service.

Comment: This code just remove db if it exist and then create new db. This is just sample console application. After db creation I run my rest service and works with it and then I call first time Membership.ValidateUser I got this error then application works as expected.

Comment: If possible, could you post the MemberShip.ValidateUser method?  I have a feeling that it's somehow attempting to create the database again.

Comment: It is standart Membership method. I don't use my own implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory.

You are trying to create an object (ex: table, sp, view, etc.) that is named `Applications` but that object already exists in the database.

Maybe you didn't remove it after initial testing.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're trying to run it on the right project:

Check your migrations folder, the Up method of your InitialCreate class is probably trying to create the Application table. You can either

Drop the table and run the code again

or

Set up your InitialCreate properly to handle this scenario